# Connections breaks includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, graphql-ruby

I have a following setup:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :variants
end

class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end

Types::QueryType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  connection :products, Types::ProductType.connection_type do
    resolve -> (obj, _, _) do
      Product.all.includes(:variants)
    end
  end
end

Types::ProductType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  connection :variants, Types::VariantType.connection_type do
    resolve -> (obj, _, _) { obj.variants }
  end
end
```

And running a following query:

```
{
  products {
    edges {
      nodes {
        variants {
          edges {
            node {
              id
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

produces following SQL queries:

```
  Product Load (2.7ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 25]]
  Variant Load (8.6ms)  SELECT "variants".* FROM "variants" WHERE "variants"."product_id" IN (1, 2, 3)
  Variant Load (19.0ms)  SELECT  "variants".* FROM "variants" WHERE "variants"."product_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["product_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 25]]
  Variant Load (13.6ms)  SELECT  "variants".* FROM "variants" WHERE "variants"."product_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["product_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 25]]
  Variant Load (2.4ms)  SELECT  "variants".* FROM "variants" WHERE "variants"."product_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["product_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 25]]
```

As we can see in the sql output, `includes` works but graphql don't care and makes a n+1 anyway. Is that normal behaviour and i'm forced to use solutions like graphql-batch to fix that or something is not right with my setup? As far as i have seen all over the internet, using `includes` should be enough for such simple scenario and graphql should use the eager loaded data instead of producing the n+1. Have i done anything wrong in here?

I'm on graphql-ruby 1.7.9

Answer (score 0):

I just received [a reply](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/issues/2084#issuecomment-460287590) on graphql-ruby issue tracker :

> Hey, I noticed that LIMIT 25 is being applied to those queries. Do you
>   know where that's being applied? If you want to use the result from
>   the initial query, you should remove the LIMIT clause. (I'm guessing
>   that if you ask for .limit(25), ActiveRecord won't use a cached
>   relation.) Maybe you have a default_max_page_size? What happens if you
>   remove it?

So, long story short, i removed the `default_max_page_size` config from my schema and it resolved the issue.